# Can't sort an array in ARM. It's sorted, but there are numbers missing and duplicated

Tags: sorting, assembly, arm, bubble-sort

I'm trying to implement a BubbleSort in ARM.

Here's main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 9

int sort(int*,int);

int main(){
        int array[SIZE] = {5,6,2,5,8,4,1,75,4};
        printf("Array before sort:\n");
        for(int i=0;i<SIZE;++i)
                printf("%d ",array[i]);
        sort(array,SIZE);
        printf("\nArray after sort:\n");
        for (int i=0;i<SIZE;++i)
                printf("%d ",array[i]);
        printf("\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Here's sort.s:

```
.global sort
.type sort%function

array   .req r0
offset_end .req r1
offset_1 .req r2
offset_2 .req r3
min_1   .req r4
min_2   .req r5

sort:
        mov ip,#4
        mul offset_end,r1,ip    // calculate final offset (in r1 there was the size)
        mov offset_1,#0    // initialize first offset to the first position
        mov offset_2,#4    // initialize second offset to the second position
loop1:
        cmp offset_1,offset_end
        beq end    // if I reached the end, it goes to end
        ldr min_1,[array,offset_1]    // get the corresponding int
        push {ip,lr}    // save lr
        mov offset_2,offset_1    // put the offset_1 in the second offset (that will be used in the loop2)
        add offset_2,offset_2,#4    // move second offset to next element
        bl loop2    // enter in the second loop
        pop {ip,lr}
        add offset_1,offset_1,#4
        b loop1
loop2:
        cmp offset_2,offset_end
        bxge lr     // if the second offset reached the end, it returns
        ldr min_2,[array,offset_2]    // get the value
        cmp min_1,min_2
        push {ip,lr}    // save lr
        blge swap    // if min_1 is greater than min_2, it swaps
        pop {ip,lr}
        add offset_2,offset_2,#4     // go to next value
        b loop2     // repeat the loop2
swap:
        str min_2,[array,offset_1]    // put the new min in the offset of the first loop
        str min_1,[array,offset_2]    // put the old min in the offset of the second loop
        bx lr     //returns
end:
        bx lr     // exit the program
```

Output:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc main.c sort.s 
$ ./a.out 
Array before sort:
5 6 2 5 8 4 1 75 4 
Array after sort:
4 5 6 6 6 8 8 8 75
```

As you can see, the array is sorted, but there are missing numbers and duplicate numbers. How can I find the bug?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you had commented your code to indicate what you think it does.  Debugging uncommented code is a lot harder than debugging commented code.  Why do you make this harder for others?

Comment: @fuz you are right, I added some comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I'll try and have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that after `swap`, `min_1` and `min_2` no longer correspond to the array entries at `offset_1` and `offset_2` but you assume that at least `min_1` does.  To fix this, update `min_1` in the `swap` function to the value at index `offset_1`, i.e. the prior value of `min_2`:

```
swap:
        str min_2,[array,offset_1]    // put the new min in the offset of the first loop
        str min_1,[array,offset_2]    // put the old min in the offset of the second loop
        mov min_1, min_2              // update min_1 to new minimum
        bx lr     //returns
```

Another thing you should fix is that your code does not preserve registers `r4` and `r5` despite that being mandated by the ABI.  To fix this, push these registers on the stack at the start of the function and pop them back off at the end.

Comment: @Sperly1987 Always happy to help!

Comment: There is no requirement to preserve `ip`.

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin Thanks.  I have confused this.